# TCL: using twapi package to get printer details

Tags: tcl

I am using twapi 4.1 version to get the details of a printer ("myprinter).
Below command works and gives me expected results.

```
set printerData [twapi::recordarray getlist [twapi::enumerate_printers] -filter {{-name eq myprinter -nocase}}]
```

However, I cannot pass the printer name as an argument to -filter option.

Below code doesn't work:

```
set printerName "myprinter"
set printerData [twapi::recordarray getlist [twapi::enumerate_printers] -filter {{-name eq $printerName -nocase}}]
```

I tried different formats (using subst command and all) but nothing worked.

Any idea how can I pass the printer name as an argument? Thanks in advance for your help.

--Nik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that tcl doesn't evaluate the string inside curly braces, so you should change your code using the *list* command instead:

```
set printerName "myprinter"
set printerData [twapi::recordarray getlist \
                 [twapi::enumerate_printers] \
                  -filter [list [list -name eq $printerName -nocase ] ]\
                 ]
```